# How to call children method from parent's constructor?

Tags: reactjs

**Usage:**

```
<SegmentedControl activeSegmentKey="c">
    <Segment key="a" label="SegmentA" />
    <Segment key="b" label="SegmentB" />
    <Segment key="c" label="SegmentC" />
</SegmentedControl>
```

The question is how to call Segment.activate method from `SegmentedControl.constructor()`.

*I can't do this now because all children of props.children are Objects, but not Segments.*

I know there is always another way to achieve the same. For example, during `SegmentedControl.render()`.

*I can pass all props(e.g active) that I need for initialization purposes to Segment child.*

The other way is set `onRef` just for the default Segment child.

Despite this, I would like to know how I can call children methods from parent's constructor, of course, if this reasonable philosophy in React world.

```
class Segment extends Component
{
   // ....

   constructor(props)
   {
       super(props);

       this.state = {
                     isActive: false
       }
    }

   activate = (onoff = true) =>
   {
        this.setState({
                        isActive: onoff
        });
   }

   onClick = (event) =>
   {
       this.context.switchSegment(this);
   };

   render()
   {
       let className = "Segment";

       if (this.state.isActive) {
            className += ' SegmentActive';
       }

       return (
            <div className={className}>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.onClick.bind(this)}><span>{this.props.label}</span></a>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

class SegmentedControl extends Component
{
   // ...

   activeSegment = null;

   constructor(props)
   {
       super(props);

       // ...

       if (this.activeSegment) {
           this.activeSegment.activate(true); // Error! because this.activeSegment is Object
       }
   }

   getChildContext()
   {
        var self = this;
        return {
            switchSegment: (segment) => {
                segment.activate(true); // Ok (segment is Segment)
                self.activeSegment.activate(false); // First call is also bad(self.activeSegment is Object)
                self.activeSegment = segment;
            }
        };
    };

   render()
   {
        return (
            <div className='SegmentedControl'>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

[Live code](http://www.react.run/BkKIzHwCZ/2)

[Final solution](http://www.react.run/BkKIzHwCZ/3)

Comment: Will you please create a plunkr for this ?

Comment: @Vivek Doshi http://www.react.run/BkKIzHwCZ/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using composition.

You can change `SegmentControl` render to something like this :

```
render() {
    return <div>
        {this.props.children.map((child, index) => {
             return <Segment ref={(ref) => this[index] = ref}>
                 {child}
             </Segment>
        }
    </div>
}
```

Which means that you can replace your components tree to something like this :

```
<SegmentedControl activeSegmentKey="c">
    <label key="a">SegmentA</label>
    <label key="b">SegmentB</label>
    <label key="c">SegmentC</label>
</SegmentedControl>
```

Comment: This looks reliable but I have implemented in a different way, have a glance if you wish.

Comment: Well, you're not forced to use `props.children`. You may add a `segments` props to `SegmentControl` which is an array of object with shape `{ key: string, label: sring}` and send these objects as props of `Segment`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [cloneElement](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#cloneelement) to achieve that:

```
<div className='SegmentedControl'>
  {React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {
    isActive: YOUR_ACTIVE_RULE,
  }
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, useful to know, but looks quite "hacky".

Comment: Bad idea. It's a bad practice and you looses some cool stuff such as Auto-complete or linters.

Comment: @danilabagroff If its "hacky" it shouldn't be in react docs, right?

Comment: Maybe change your approach and leave segment responsibility only to `Segment` component.